# General solution to updating fields for table in Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: entity-framework-4

I want to create a method which can takes the properties I possibly may update and leaving those not interested untouched.

Here is what I did:

```
public static void updateTable(int id, string field1, string field2, string field3){
    using(var context = new Entities()){
        var obj = context.Table.Where(x=>x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if(obj != null){
            obj.field1 = field1;
            ...

            obj.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

But in this pattern, I need to pass all 4 parameters into the method even I just want to update only one field. Is there any generic solution to update only the fields I passed in?

I came up something like this:

```
public static void updateTable(int id, object data_json){
    using(var context = new Entities()){
        var obj = context.Table.Where(x=>x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if(obj != null){
            if(data_json['field1']!=null) //something like this
                obj.field1 = data_json['field1'];
            ...

            obj.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

But this can't handle the case that I do want to set a field to be null. Or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about updating *relationships*, you can use **[ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx)**, which only updates the *scalar* properties.

E.g:

```
public static void updateTable(int id, object data_json){
   using(var context = new Entities()) {
      var obj = context.Table.Where(x=>x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
      context.ApplyCurrentValues("Table", data_json);
   }
}
```

It assumes an entity with the same key is already attached in the graph. In this case, the query for `var obj` will ensure the object is in the graph, then it's contents are overridden with the scalar properties on the supplied object.

You might need an explicit cast on `data_json` to ensure it is of the same type contained in the entity set.

Comment: when I tried this and only set 1 out of 3 possible scalar properties, `ApplyCurrentValues` set the other 2 properties to `null`.  Is there some way to have `ApplyCurrentValues` only update the values that I set, leaving unchanged properties alone?

Answer (score 0):

Using an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487338.aspx) would allow you to send in only the properties you want to set, and would allow you to specify `null` values as well.

For example:

```
public static void updateTable(int id, dynamic data){
    using(var context = new Entities()){
        var obj = context.Table.Where(x=>x.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        if(obj != null){
            if (((IDictionary<string, object>)data).ContainsKey("field1"))
                obj.field1 = data.field1;
            ...

            obj.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

and you could call it like this:

```
dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();

data.field1 = 123;
data.field2 = null;
data.field5 = "abc";

MyClass.updateTable(1, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be solved with a moment of reflection. This function solves the problem:

```
    public void UpdateTable(int id, object values)
    {
        using (var entities = new MyEntities())
        {
            var valuesType = values.GetType();
            var element = entities.MyTable.Where(t => t.ID == id).First();

            //We are iterating through all properties of updated element and checking
            //if there is value provided for there properties in values parameter
            foreach (var property in element.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                var valuesProperty = valuesType.GetProperty(property.Name);
                //If values contain this property
                if (valuesProperty != null)
                {
                    //taking value out of values parameter
                    var value = valuesProperty.GetValue(values, null);
                    //setting it in our element to update
                    property.SetValue(element, value, null);
                }
            }

            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
UpdateTable(125, new { FieldA = 1, FieldB = "ABCD" });
```

You can even make this method more universal by adding generic table type parameter.